# Tips on managing all the godly wonders of information?

Tags: multitasking

Ever since I started coding back in 2008 I was addicted to it and I still am today. Typically not a day goes by that I don't touch some code. What the hell is my point... I'll get to it soon I promise. I have been writing PHP for roughly a year, I absolutely love it and HTML for 2, and I can't get enough of them. However, I want to broaden my skill set to a larger field. At the moment, I find HTML really boring, in fact the UI (specifically HTML) is the portion of my projects I want to do the least. I know some Ruby, Python, java, C, and Perl; but I want to become as proficient in a few of these as I am in PHP.

I want to focus mainly on Ruby/ROR and learning Objective-C/Cocoa. I have books out of the ying-yang, but I have yet to fully finish reading any of them.

Finally what begs the question, how in the world can I focus on all of this yet at the same time keep doing what I am going with PHP (which is making medium size applications). I have the determination and I'm not going anywhere (I'm to young to like die or something), any tips?

Comment: Hmm, how about coding yourself a time machine? = P Slow down a bit, son, you just can't learn it all. Jack of all trades, master of none.

Comment: Work it out, grasshopper. Only you can decide what you want to focus on.

Comment: Should be community wiki. To focus, just find something you can focus on. Any problem which is easy to get started but hard to solve. Or, jump between little projects and return to old ones when you have a new idea. Maybe it just feels like you're going slowly because you're young, just hang in and you'll be a whiz before you know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is really about productivity and not programming, but I think it deserves an answer) Find a project that you're so passionate about, that if you don't finish it *right now* you will go insane. Then find a piece of the project that you can finish tonight. Then find a smaller piece that you can finish before you go to dinner. Finish that piece. After that, [don't break the chain](http://lifehacker.com/281626/jerry-seinfelds-productivity-secret).

Also, don't multitask. You think you're good at it, but you're not (don't worry, no one is).

Comment: Would be a different story if you were female....eh! Wish i could multitask like a female, then things would be so much easier.... :)

Comment: Ditto on the +1 for don't multitask (and the other advice). Attempting to do everything at once has caused me to accomplish very little for a long time! Of course, it depends how much drive and focus you have (I'm a lethargic scatterbrain). YMMV.

Comment: Good advice, I think that I am going to focus mainly on Ruby and posibaly throw Objective-C in (as long as I don't explode due to access info), but take breaks in between each language so I do not get bored. For instance do some ruby today, Objective-C tomorrow then both the next day. I find that I am able to retain the little bit of information that I obtain very well especially when I reiterate what I learn.

I suppose it will all work out in the end. Very good answer, made me think...